# PHP update table by form

Tags: php, forms, html-table

I'm trying to update a table from a form.

I have 3 pages. The first one queries all of the rows from my table with an "edit" link.
When edit is clicked (page 2) the code pulls the $id and puts it in the url. The $id is pulled from the url and is used in a query to fill a form.

My problem is passing the updated form info to my table. Basically the update isn't happening.

Second page

```
<?php

  include '../db/config.php';
  include '../db/opendb.php';

$id = $_GET["id"]; 

  $order = "SELECT * FROM tableName where id='$id'";
  $result = mysql_query($order);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

  ?>

  <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo "$row[id]"?>">
    <tr>        
      <td>Title</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="title" size="20" value="<?php echo"$row[title]"?>">
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Post</td>
    <td>
<input type="text" name="post" size="40" value="<?php echo
  "$row[post]"?>">
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">
<input type="submit" name="submit value" value="Edit">
</td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

third page

```
          include '../db/config.php';
      include '../db/opendb.php';

   $query = "UPDATE tableName SET '$_POST[title]', '$post[post]' WHERE id='$id'";
        mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Troubleshoot the query functioning with a database UI like phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Please note that the community is moving towards using PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php Using this is not only easy but will save you from sql injection attacks!

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: Don't edit your question to invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST[title])){
$title = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['title']));
    }else{
$title = NULL;
    }

if (isset($_POST[post])){
$post = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['post']));
    }else{
$post = NULL;
    }


$query = "UPDATE tableName SET title='$title', post='$post' WHERE id='$id'";           
mysql_query($query);
```

I would also recommend mysqli functions instead of mysql and I probably wouldn't call a variable  and table column 'post' to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks so much I also had to pass id to the 3rd page also with the     if (isset($_POST[id])){
$id = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['id']));
    }else{
$id = NULL;
    }

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
UPDATE tableName SET `title` = {$_POST['title']}, `post` = {$_POST['post']}...
```

Ask yourself, what are you setting?

Comment: I also think you need to surround the $_POST with {} aswell, I don't think the string gets formatted correctly otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement for the database update is wrong. It should include a listing of not only the new values but also the **corresponding field names**. This means it should look more like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE tableName SET `title` = {$_POST['title']}, `post` = {$_POST['post']} WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Notice that you also should embrace fields of `$_POST` inside of strings with curly brackets (`{}`) or put them outside of the quotes. (like `" = " .$_POST['title']. ", "`). This is absolutely necessary if you use the standard way to access those with he quotes (e.g. not `$_POST[title]` but `$_POST['title']` or `$_POST["title"]`).

Additionally you should add the following to your code:

- *Some error handling*, currently you don't even know if something went wrong. The simplest way is to check the return value of the `mysql_query()` function for `null` and if it is `null`, get the mysql error message with `mysql_error()`.
- *Escaping for passed values.* Currently you directly pass the posted data into a mysql query which is very insecure. (See for example *SQL-Injection* [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) You should use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on all form data before inserting them into queries. This escapes all parts that could be malicious.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not setting the values. In the statement:

```
$query = "UPDATE tableName SET '$_POST[title]', '$post[post]' WHERE id='$id'";
```

you should pass column names to be updated.

Comment: $query="Update tableName (title, post) WHERE id='$id'"
VALUES
('$_POST[title]','$_POST[post]')";

Comment: @hobbywebsite do remember to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using PDO statements yet to prevent SQL injection attacks then you should use more protection then just mysql_real_escape_string(). On top of escaping the data you should be validating that the submitted data is in fact what you are expecting.

Ie. In your code here:

```
  $id = $_GET["id"]; 

  $order = "SELECT * FROM tableName where id='$id'";
  $result = mysql_query($order);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

If you added:

```
if(is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
   $id = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET["id"]));

   $order = "SELECT id, title, post FROM tableName where id='$id'";
   $result = mysql_query($order);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  }
```

This would at least validate what you are executing is in fact an ID number (That is, if ID is actually a number ;) . You can apply this logic to all your inputs if you are not yet using PDO statements. If you are expecting letters then validate for letters, numbers validate for numbers, escape special characters. Again, this is bare minimum. I would really suggest reading up on the hundreds of SQL injection techniques and start reading up on PDO's.

Also, in regards to using the SELECT * statement. I would try and avoid it. It adds a layer of vulnerability to your statements, if you change the order of the fields in your table and you are using $row[0] (Numbered requests) it can muck things up and lastly if your table contains additional fields with data that is unrelated to the ones you need then you are using on this page then you are loading information you don't need to.

```
 $order = "SELECT id, title, post FROM tableName where id='$id'";
```

Would solve that nicely. :)  Good luck!